# Python libraries folder

Tags: python, anaconda, package

every time I install a python library, this package is installed in
C: \ Users \ User \ Miniconda3 \ Lib \ site-packages
This is perfect for me if I run the program in the ANACONDA environment, but when I want to run it outside of anaconda, opening python directly, the libraries look for them in
C: \ Users \ User \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Lib

my solution is, every time I install a library, I copy the library from
C: \ Users \ User \ Miniconda3 \ Lib \ site-packages
to
C: \ Users \ User \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Lib

Is there any way so that when I run python outside of anaconda, the folder where python looks for libraries and packages is
C: \ Users \ User \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python39 \ Lib?

[Image ref.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfMBA.png)

Comment: How do you do the install? Are you using the `conda` command? Use python's `pip` for install into your other python. Something like `python -m pip install mymodule` (depending on how you run python). Or maybe `pip3 install mymodule`.

Comment: I use pip install 
for example C:\Users\edgarleon>pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\edgarleon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\edgarleon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in c:\users\edgarleon\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)
...

Comment: If I run in the anaconda environment, it works perfect for me, but if I want to run outside of anaconda, such as creating a scheduled task or using the pyinstaller, it looks in the other folder for the libraries and not in the miniconda